# Makefile install copy executable to usr/local/bin Linux

Tags: linux, makefile

In my Makefile I'm trying to copy the executable file into `usr/local/bin`.

```
install:
    sudo cp program1 usr/local/bin
```

My Makefile and program1-file is in a directory `src` in Documents so this doesn't work. I probably need the whole path from my `src` directory.

Is there a general way to make it work regardless of where I put my directory with the Makefile and executable? Maybe using the `PATH` variable or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`usr/local/bin` is a relative path. If you don't want that, use an absolute path:

```
install:
    cp whatever /usr/local/bin
```

Some tips:

- Don't use sudo in your Makefile, that's unusual. Note in the installation docs that the `install` target has to be run by a user with sufficient privileges (and people will do `sudo make install` when they want to)
- Look into the `install` (`man install`), it's meant for this sort of thing.

Comment: Even better, use a `$DESTDIR` prefix variable and the `install` program, so `install whatever $DESTDIR/usr/local/bin`